# type *gin.Context has no field or method SaveUploadedFile

Tags: go, go-gin

My code works fine on my computer but I get this compile-time error on my server after I moved the code to the Debian server:

```
type *gin.Context has no field or method SaveUploadedFile
```

I use [sample gin code](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/examples/upload-file/single/main.go) to save file:

```
    if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(file, file.Filename); err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("upload file err: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }
```

I have upgraded go to 1.8.3 on the server (to be of the same version as go on my desktop) and updated gin afterwards, hoping to solve the issue. But it did not.

Here is my `go env`:

```
root@s1:~# go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/srv/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

I have also tried:

```
rm -rf $GOPATH/pkg/*
```

I also tried  `go build -a`, but get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your server is using old codebase of gin. Just checked the gin commit history.

The method `SaveUploadedFile` added [5 days ago](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/commit/93b3a0d7ec95c33dc327397ab1756c36853328ee). So execute below command to pull the latest codebase on your server.

```
go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

Then compile it.

Comment: Can you verify file `$GOPATH/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go` on your server has `SaveUploadedFile` method?

Comment: `"SaveUploadedFile" not found`! What can I do now?

Comment: It means on your server side, you have old codebase. Delete this directory `$GOPATH/src/github.com/gin-gonic` and do `go get -u` as in my answer. Then verify the file again.

Comment: You are my man! Problem solved. Please elaborate your answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually solution is in the answer, for some reason go get command didn't do its job (typically it suppose to work) on your server. I come to know from interacting with you. Then I suggested you to do manual clean and get fresh codebase.

Comment: Yes, that's weird behavior. Apparently go update is not very reliable, at least in some circumstances . I run `go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin` at least 3 times before posting my question.